# Allow user to control audio playing on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to create a feature on my webpage that allows users to turn audio on/off by hitting the number 4 on their keyboard.

Audio should automatically play the first time the webpage loads. However using local storage, if they decide to turn off audio, that should be saved, and if they are to re-load/refresh, audio should stay off.

Can someone explain why this isn't working?

```
localStorage.setItem("preference", "isMusicPlaying");
var audio = document.getElementById('music');
var musicPlaying = localStorage.getItem("preference");
if(musicPlaying == false) {
    audio.play();
}
else {
    audio.pause();
}
document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";

document.body.onkeyup = function(pressFour){
    if(pressFour.keyCode == 52) {
        if(musicPlaying==false) {
            audio.play();
            document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("off").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "0";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "75";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "75";
            document.getElementById('music').play();
        }
        else if(musicPlaying==true) {
            audio.pause();
            document.getElementById("on").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("off").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "75";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "75";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "0";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById('music').pause();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "container">
 <audio id="music" src="/music/orgmusic.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <img id ="titleimg"src = "images/titleimage.png">
        <h1>Please click one of the following!</h1>
    <div class = "navigation">
        1. Travel the trail<img id="wagon"src = "images/wagon.png"></br></br>
        2. Learn about the trail<img id="info"src = "images/info.png"></br></br>
        3. See the Oregon Top 10<img id="ten"src = "images/top10.png"></li></br></br>
        4. Turn Sound (<span id="off">Off</span>/<span id="on">On</span>)
        <img id="sound"src="images/volume.png"><img id="nosound"src = "images/mute.png"></br></br>
    </div>
    <div class = "landscape">
        <img id ="grass"src = "images/grassyfield.png">
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mainmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css">

<script src="/JS/mainmenu.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JS/global.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code immediately sets a localStorage variable to the the string "isMusicPlaying", and I don't see why. What you can do instead is to only check what it equals - If it equals null, that means it has not been set.

Here is the code I would suggest. In the start, we check if the localStorage musicPlaying variable is null (which means it's not set) or true (which means it was playing before we reloaded). Then I made play and pause functions which do what your code already did, but they also update the localStorage musicPlaying variable. Additionally, I made a playPause function that checks if the localStorage musicPlaying variable is set to true or false, and executes `play()` or `pause()` accordingly.

```
var audio = document.getElementById('music');
if (localStorage.getItem("musicPlaying") === null) play()
else if (localStorage.getItem("musicPlaying") === "true") play()


function play() {
    localStorage.setItem("musicPlaying", "true")
    audio.play();
    document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("off").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "75";
    document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "75";
    document.getElementById('music').play();
}
function pause() {
    localStorage.setItem("musicPlaying", "false")
    audio.pause();
    document.getElementById("on").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("off").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "75";
    document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "75";
    document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "0";
    document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById('music').pause();
}
function playPause() {
    var musicPlaying = localStorage.getItem("musicPlaying")
    if (musicPlaying == "true") pause()
    else if (musicPlaying == "false") play()
} 
document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";

document.body.onkeypress = function(pressFour){
  if(pressFour.keyCode == 52) playPause();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Edit, i realized in your playPause function, there is an x before "musicPlaying". Now it works..THANKS!

Comment: @stackoverflowoverflow It works in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spectralkh/maLyjfrk/33/

Try understanding the code and putting in console.log statements.

Comment: @stackoverflowoverflow Would appreciate if you accepted the answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a `flag` variable, which you will save in local storage. So, I'd suggest something along these lines:

```
const audio = document.getElementById('music');
const musicPlaying = localStorage.getItem("preference");
// The flag variable.
let musicPlaying = false;

if(musicPlaying == false) {
    audio.play();
}
else {
    audio.pause();
}
document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";

document.body.onkeyup = function(pressFour){
    if(pressFour.keyCode == 52) {
        if(musicPlaying==false) {
            audio.play();
            document.getElementById("on").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("off").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "0";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "75";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "75";
            document.getElementById('music').play();
        }
        else if(musicPlaying==true) {
            audio.pause();
            document.getElementById("on").style.color = "black";
            document.getElementById("off").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.height = "75";
            document.getElementById("nosound").style.width = "75";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.height = "0";
            document.getElementById("sound").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById('music').pause();
        }
        // This will toggle between false/true on each press of the button.
        musicPlaying = !musicPlaying;
        // NOW we save the flag variable into local storage
        localStorage.setItem("preference", musicPlaying)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.